# How to install cocoa pods

Tags: cocoapods

I want to install Cocoa Pods, with the command `sudo gem install cocoapods`, but terminal show this error:

> YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version
>   that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
>       Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/fuzzy_match

How can I resolve it? Thank a lot!

Comment: Try `gem install fuzzy_match` and show terminal response.

Comment: YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
Fetching: fuzzy_match-2.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.  Thank you for ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have permissions to run executables from `/usr/bin`, so you need to pass folder where to install `cocoapods` with proper permissions.

There are 2 ways:

#### Create new folder for `GEM_HOME`

```
mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
gem install cocoapods
```

When installation finished

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
```

#### Install Cocoa Pods to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

`-n` flag tells where binary files will be located.

Comment: YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.3.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.3.1
1 gem installed

Comment: What's the problem? You've successfully installed Cocoa Pods. To remove YAML warning update `psych` and that's all.

Comment: @PietroP. If my answer solved your problem please accept it.

Comment: @PietroP. To accept an answer click on checkmark icon under answer rating )) That's how everything works here on StackOverflow ))